# After porting ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0,request DateTime not deserialized properly and throwing error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm porting a simple web API from asp.net core 2.2 to asp.net core 3.0 and getting a serialization error after sending a request to an action.

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime. Path: $.DateOfBirth | LineNumber: 6 | BytePositionInLine: 28.

The data contract (request) has not changed whatsoever: I have literally copied a request DTO from 1 solution to another, and the same data annotations exist on the DTO as shown below.

```
        [Required]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

This is the request json field

```
    "DateOfBirth": "01/01/1980",
```

Why is asp.net core 2.2 able to properly deserialize this, but asp.net core 3.0 not?
Any insights?

For the new asp.net core 3.0 project, I am using

```
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="4.6.0" />
```

If I was to be able to change the json field value to a format such as

```
1980-01-01T00:00:00
```

I no longer get the error. However, I cannot change the json field value sent from clients since I have many client applications that are dependent on the web api and coordinating that change would be a long process. So I need to keep the contract the same.

Ive located the following text from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support

> Attempting to deserialize representations that don't conform to the profile will cause JsonSerializer to throw a JsonException:

I need to work around this since I cannot change what the client application are sending.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support) should clear it up.

Comment: @KirkLarkin, Can you please be more specific?

Comment: The docs I linked explain how the difference between 2.2 and 3.0 is in how JSON is processed. It used to be JSON.NET, but is now the `System.Text.Json` types. You can either switch back to JSON.NET in 3.0 or, well, you've answered that part yourself now. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work in the short term for a solution

```
            services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
        });
```

and

```
    public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Debug.Assert(typeToConvert == typeof(DateTime));
        return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString());
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZ"));
    }
}
```